# Recommendations for object detection

Tags: computer-vision, detection

At present, there are several directions to consider: open vocabulary object detection, open set object detection, semi-supervised, weakly supervised, directional object detection, 3D object detection.

I hope you can recommend one of the above directions or other good directions for Posting. However, it is also necessary to consider computing resources, at present, a person in the laboratory is only equipped with a 3090, and they may only borrow one or two copies at ordinary times. I can borrow my  senior fellow apprentice's when I need more resources for the final experiment.

At present, there are several directions to consider: open vocabulary object detection, open set object detection, semi-supervised, weakly supervised, directional object detection, 3D object detection.